# Find the area of the portion of the sphere that lies inside a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I would much appreciate any help with this problem I have been given.

Consider the sphere $x^2$ +$y^2$ + $z^2$ = $a^2$.

Find the *surface* area of the portion of the sphere that lies inside the cylinder $x^2$ + $y^2$ = $b^2$.

Comment: If it's beyond what he taught you, it would be better to ask your professor why he assigned this problem in the first place. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I volunteer for the case b>a, it is 100%. Half the work done !

Answer (score 0):

A sphere in $3$ dimensions has the remarkable property (not shared by spheres in any other dimensions) that the surface area of a slice is proportional to the height of the slice. If $b\le a$, the two spherical caps inside the infinite cylinder each have height $a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$, and the sphere has total surface area $4\pi a^2$ distributed over a total height of $2a$, so the surface area of the spherical caps is

$$
\frac{2(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}{2a}\cdot4\pi a^2=4\pi a^2\left(1-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac ba\right)^2}\right)\;.
$$

It’s not entirely clear from the question whether you also want to include the surface area of the cut; this is a cylindrical surface of radius $b$ and height $2(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})$, so it would contribute another term

$$4\pi b(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})=4\pi ab\left(1-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac ba\right)^2}\right)\;.$$

As has already been stated in the comments, if $b\gt a$ then the entire surface area $4\pi a^2$ of the sphere is inside the infinite cylinder.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I apologise, I misread it as area, when it is actually surface area. I was not the person who downvoted your answer btw! Its a perfect answer regardless!

Comment: @david.miles: Thanks for correcting the question – but does it make a difference? I had assumed that surface area was meant; I don't know what other area could have been meant. It does make it sound a bit more like the cylindrical surface is also included, but I'd already calculated that anyway.

Comment: you were right, it does not actually make a difference, it was just a silly mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Length of equator times  spherical caps total height
$$= {2(a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2})}\cdot 2\pi a $$